# Unexpected Buffered Reader Behavior: skipping odd-numbered lines

Tags: java, bufferedreader, eof

I am experiencing very strange behavior with BufferedReader. I want to read an entire file however it only reads every other line.

E.g   the file below

> 1 //ignore the left most space - shouldn't exist
>   2
>    3
>    4
>    5
>    6

Will output

> 2
>    4
>    6

Here is some of my code...

```
    fileRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( new FileInputStream(file)));

     public void scan(){

    if (fileRead != null){

        try{    
        while ((fileRead.readLine()) != null){
           String line = fileRead.readLine();   
        String abcLine = line;
        System.out.println(line);
          }
        }catch(IOException e) {
         System.out.println("Line can not be read");
        }
}else{ System.out.println("Can not Read - File Not Found"); }

}
```

My best bet is the bug lies within the while statement. Is this the correct way to ensure 
you read the file until you reach EOF "end of file" ?

Any insight is truly appreciated

Thank you!

Comment: You call `readLine` twice.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily call the behavior "weird"; `BufferedReader` *is* behaving as advertised and doing exactly what you told it to do.

Answer (score 2):

You're reading two lines each time through the loop. Your current code is:

```
while ((fileRead.readLine()) != null){  // reads a line, ignores it
    String line = fileRead.readLine();  // reads another line, stores in 'line'
    ... // do stuff with 'line'
}
```

Every call to `readLine()` reads a line. You probably want something more like:

```
String line;
while ((line = fileRead.readLine()) != null) {
   ... // do stuff with 'line'
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Jason C the second I posted it I realized what I was doing wrong.